# Objective C and Objective C++

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

C files can be modified *from `.c` to `.m` files* and can be *called from* other Objective C files (`.m` files).

C++ files can be modified *from `.cpp` to `.mm` files* and can be *called from* other Objective C++ files (`.mm` files).

*`.m` files* can be *called from `.mm` files*. But *`.mm` files cannot be called from `.m` files*.

Is *Objective C++* coding *necessary* in iPhone development as *UI* will be in Objective C and any other protocols implemented can't be Objective C++ as this (protocols written) will be *called from the UI which is written Objective C*.

In what *scenario* is this *Objective C++* coding used?

Comment: Please highlight with stars (`*...*` or `**...**`) not backticks (`\`...\``). The latter is used for formatting inline code.

Comment: @KennyTM:Thanks for telling me of how to do formatting.Will do it right from my next formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .m files can be called from .mm files. But .mm files cannot be called from .m files.

Not sure what you mean by this, but I think it's wrong.

The "Objective" part of Objective-C(++) is the same in both languages.  It doesn't matter whether the implementation is Objective-C or Objective-C++, the objects will be fully interoperable.

What does matter is the header file in which the interface is declared.  For instance:

```
@interface Foo
{
   CPPFoo myFoo; // A C++ object
}

@end
```

can't be included in a normal Objective-C `.m` file because C++ classes are illegal in C.  One way to get around this is to use forward declarations and pointers e.g.

```
#if defined __cplusplus
class CPPFoo;
#else
typedef struct CPPFoo CPPFoo;
#endif

@interface Foo
{
   CPPFoo *myFoo; // NOTE: a pointer to a C++ object
}

@end
```

You need to new the pointer in `-init` and delete it in `-dealloc/-finalize`

---

> Is Objective C++ coding necessary in iPhone development

No.  I used to think (coming from a C++ background) that it would be best to use C++ everywhere and Objective-C only in the UI.  However, it didn't take long for me to realise that Objective-C's object model is better than that of C++.   So now I would consider C++ in only two cases:

- when interfacing to libraries that were written in C++
- if performance is important and you need an built in Object model (i.e. you don't want to use pure C)

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C++ is used whenever you want to mix Objective-C code and C++ code.

Your statement that ".mm files cannot be called from .m files" is not true. If you put C++ *in the header* then you can't call it from a pure Objective-C file, but you can have a purely Objective-C interface for a class that has an implementation that uses C++. A common example is wrapping an existing C++ class (perhaps some existing library) as an Objective-C class.