# acces c++ datamember in objective-c class

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

What I'm trying to do is quite simple but I probably have the syntax wrong.

I have an Objective-C Interface with a `Note class` parameter. Note.h is a C++ class that basically looks like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Note {
public:
    string name;
    Note(string name){
        this->name = name; // ERROR: Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note'
    }

};
```

This is my controller where is using Note. I changed the file extension to .mm

```
@class Note;
@interface InstrumentGridViewController : UIViewController {
@public
    Note* note;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Note* note;
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
@implementation InstrumentGridViewController
@synthesize note;

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    note = Note("fa"); // ERROR: Cannot convert 'Note' to 'Note*' in assignment
    NSLog(@"naam van de noot is %s", note->name); // ERROR: Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note'
}
```

I'm getting these three errors though (I've added them as comments on the right lines)

Any idea how what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate the `Note` object using `new`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (note != 0)
        delete note;
    note = new Note("fa");
    NSLog(@"naam van de noot is %s", note->name.c_str());
}
```

However it doesn't seem right to be doing that in the button press action method...

Also don't forget to `delete` it in your object's `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    delete note;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Lastly your `@property` attribute `retain` is wrong as it's not an Objective-C object; instead use `assign` and better still make it `readonly`.

A better way to initialise most objects is by using a `const` reference to them rather than a copy:

```
Note(const string &name)
{
    this->name = name;
}
```

Comment: ... and don't forget to delete the old note in `buttonPressed:`

Comment: Where or when should I allocate the object than? The `buttonPressed` is the first time when I need to use it so that's why I thought I'd do it there.

Comment: Also, adding `new` fixed the `cannot convert` problem but I'm still getting `Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note'` when I try to use the `note` object in my NSLog function. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @Sled how many `Note` objects need to be 'active' at any one time?  Is it possible to allocate one object only and then change its attributes when a button is pressed instead?  Are you `#import`ing `Note.h`?

Comment: I will need to use several Note objects but only one of them is a datamember (Note is a quite important class of which I'll be creating instances in other methods too) And I have the import statement, yes.

Comment: @Sled I have updated the answer; you need to pass the c-string of the `name` member to `NSLog()` using the `string::c_str()` method.

Comment: Even with the `c_str()` function, the error doesn't go away. I also added the const reference to my constructor but I'm still getting that  same error, `Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note'`

Answer (score 0):

Your Note C++ class is not valid. Change its declaration to be instead:

```
class Note {
public:
    string name;
    Note(string aName) {
        name = aName;
    }
};
```

Also change your `InstrumentGridViewController`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    note = new Note("fa");
    NSLog(@"naam van de noot is %s", note->name);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete note;
    [super dealloc];    // Use this only if not using ARC
}
```

Comment: How is the `Note` class declaration invalid?

Comment: Actually, using `this->` in my constructor was also giving me the `Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note` error and this fixed that problem. But the NSLog doesn't work and still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cannot find interface declaration for 'Note'` error was caused because of `@class Note` in my `Obj-C controller .h file.` It's strange because I have a working sample project where `@class` is used and it works fine.

I fixed it using forward declarations the way they are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920855/objective-c-and-objective-c) and [here.](http://www.iphonewarroom.com/2011/08/how-to-mix-objective-cm-and-ccpp-code.html)

```
// used typedef struct <classname> <classname>
typedef struct Note Note;

// instead of
@class Note
```

The above goes in the Obj-C header file. In the .mm file goes the `#import "Note.h"` statement